# Whats the difference in setting opacity and setting background as rgba(x,y,z,a)?

Tags: css

i guess i'm getting kind of same result.

Please make me clear about this properties.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Opacity :** Makes the whole element transparent including its content.
Defining opacity:

```
element{opacity:0.5}
```

**Background rgba** (Red,Green,Blue,Opacity): It only makes the element background transparent leaving its content as it is. 
Defining Background rgba: background:

```
  element{
   background:rgba(40, 41, 42, 0.5);
   }
```

In both place, opacity value extends form 0 to 1. (Where value 1 acts as total opaque and 0 as complete transparent)
To convert a hex value of color to rgb: [Here](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/hextorgb.htm)

Answer (score -1):

Opacity sets the opacity value for an element and all of its children; While RGBA sets the opacity value only for a single declaration.

This is well explained here. http://www.css3.info/introduction-opacity-rgba/

Answer (score -1):

They are not the same. Setting the background to a transparent color will do just that: the background will become see-through, but not the content. Setting the opacity affects the whole element.